# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).appendTo is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo este elemento:

```
<p class="info" style="text-align: left;">Encuentra toda la info aquí</p>
```

Y quiero moverlo a este `div`;

```
<div id="informacion"></div>
```

He intentado de las siguientes formas:

```
 $('.info').appendTo('#informacion');
 $('p.info').appendTo('#informacion');
```

Pero siempre sale el mismo error.

Comment: la etiqueta de tu publicacion dice "javascript" pero esto es jQuery, estas agregando la librería jQuery?

Comment: La etiqueta es correcta, jQuery es una librería de javascript

Comment: jQuery no es una librería nativa de JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese error te sale porque esa función que usas no esta definida porque hace falta la librería jQuery debes agregarla

Así como lo tienes ya esta bien  función [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) (este hace que se agregue al final del elemento):

**$(".info").appendTo("#informacion");**

Alternativamente, puede usar la función  [prependTo](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/) (hace que se agregue al comienzo del elemento por si tienes mas elementos dentro del mismo):

**$(".info").prependTo("#informacion");**

**Ejemplo:**

```js
 
 $("#appendTo").click(function() {
 $('.info').appendTo('#informacion');
 });
```

```css
.info {
  border: 1px solid red;
   min-height: 50px; 
}
#informacion {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="info" style="text-align: left;">Encuentra toda la info aquí</p>

<div id="informacion">
<h3>Div informacion</h3>

</div>

<button id="appendTo">Mover a #informacion</button>
```